# Izpack installer - Change window title and footer

Tags: java, izpack

I created an installer using Izpack, I wish to change the following:

1. the installer window title is Izpack - My Application name, I wish to remove the Izpack from the window title.
2. In the installer footer there is "Made by Izpack - http://izpack.org" I wish to remove that too, I'll credit Izpack in the licenses folder in the application.
3. Each of the panels have a pre-defined name such as "Target Path" or "Select Installation Package", I wish to change this text to something I think more friendly (I don't want to change the language just the text)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The best way seems to define a custom language pack and override whatever entries you want to change but there is a bug in izpack (5.0-Beta and even rc1) that prevents custom language packs from overriding entries found in the installer predefined language packs in this case you have to modify the language pack that is included in the generated installer jar (just unzip it find the language pack, change the file and zip it back) or you can download izpack source and change the language packs there so whenever an installer is created it will contain the modified language pack.

language packs are found in : izpack / izpack-core / src / main / resources / com / izforge / izpack / bin / langpacks / installer